# Twitter Bootstrap background image fill height 100%

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, height, background-image

I have a site with the standard header on top, and below it I want to have a div with a background image filling the rest of the page in height. It is still contained with the container so it's not meant to be "full-screen". Right now the is in the div but it is limited to the size of the content of #products-container. I tried making the row 100% (not even sure if that is possible) and even the container 100%. Doesn't do anything. Not that familiar with BS

This sits within the standard bs "container" class

```
<div class="row">   
        <div class="col-lg-12"  id="bg">
                <div class="col-lg-3" id="products-container">
                    <div class="op-container"><h1> PRODUCTS</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisiut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu</p>
                    </div> 

                </div>  <!-- products-container end -->
        </div>   <!-- bg end -->
     </div>
```

Some of the css applied

```
img {
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
}

#products-bg {
background-image:url('images/homesplash2.jpg');
background-size:100% 100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;    
position: relative;
}
```

Can this be done in %?

Comment: Do you want something Like [**That**](http://www.bootply.com/128594) @Clam?

Comment: that's what it's doing right now. I want the image to run all the way down the page

Comment: Use [**This**](http://www.bootply.com/128596) and change `min-height` on css as you want.

Comment: i did something similar as a fix. the problem that i have now is... it seems like when my nav bar moves down a level (shrinking the browser), the div bg image doesn't react. it just covers the nav bar. Even while it's at the top, the dropdowns are being hidden behind the bg. any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think bootstrap allows you do to this. Try increasing image height of itself and use maybe .img-responsive class on the image.

If you want the image to cover the div use

```
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: i think i found a hack for it actually, i had an id on the class "container" as well as the "row" that is above it, and put set heights on those.